# Python TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a problem here which annoyed me for several days:(

I am new to python and tensorflow.

When I was practicing tensorflow and tried to use tensorboard, I met this question.

I wrote python in PyCharm and also my python version is 3.6.

part of my code is:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logs/",sess.graph) 
sess.run(init)
```

then, I go to terminal and write the command:

```
cd /Users/Claire/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches
```

then, I see a directory called "logs" which has "events.out.tfevents.1533570728.H-MacBook-Air.local" in it.

So, i write a command under

/Users/Claire/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches

```
tensorboard --logdir='logs/'
```

then, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import audio_plugin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/audio/audio_plugin.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import metadata
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/audio/metadata.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import plugin_data_pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/audio/plugin_data_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
serialized_pb=_b('\n+tensorboard/plugins/audio/plugin_data.proto\x12\x0btensorboard\"}\n\x0f\x41udioPluginData\x12\x0f\n\x07version\x18\x01 \x01(\x05\x12\x37\n\x08\x65ncoding\x18\x02 \x01(\x0e\x32%.tensorboard.AudioPluginData.Encoding\" \n\x08\x45ncoding\x12\x0b\n\x07UNKNOWN\x10\x00\x12\x07\n\x03WAV\x10\x0b\x62\x06proto3')                   
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'
```

Can anyone help me?? 
Thank you.

Comment: Try installing tensorflow 1.9.0.  `pip install tensorflow==1.9.0`

Comment: @jfleach Hey, I just saw your comment. And I tried it. I install it and then I get this error.

Comment: Command "/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/ld/_2dfh18s7cs2t5sj0r8bp_w40000gn/T/pip-install-DHnTY9/grpcio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/ld/_2dfh18s7cs2t5sj0r8bp_w40000gn/T/pip-record-wi71CR/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ld/_2dfh18s7cs2t5sj0r8bp_w40000gn/T/pip-install-DHnTY9/grpcio/

Answer (score 0):

please uninstalle protobuf and Tensorflow, then reinstalle Tensorflow but with latest version.
Apparently the version of protobuf also.

To upodate the version :

**pip install -U protobuf**

Comment: Thank you! I follow your instruction. I install protobuf and the latest Tensorflow and also update my mac version to 10.12 and then it solved! :)